# First_value window function in Greenplum

Tags: greenplum

I am working in Greenplum DB.

Getting strange result in First_value window function when in order by clause passing string value which is common in all rows then its always return the row which was first inserted but ideally it should return any value.Below is my code...

```
create temporary table test_first_value (id int,statename 
varchar(50),episodeid int,
episodedate date) distributed by (id);

insert into test_first_value values(12,'MP',9863,'2015-11-06');
insert into test_first_value values(12,'MP',98123,'2009-11-06');
insert into test_first_value values(12,'MP',90123,'2017-03-06');
insert into test_first_value values(12,'MP',44567,'2013-03-17');
insert into test_first_value values(13,'MP',189300,'2013-03-17');
insert into test_first_value values(13,'MP',443467,'2016-03-19');
```

It is always returning the same value which was inserted first that is episodeid = 9863 for id = 12 and episodeid = 189300 for id = 13

```
Select *,
First_value(episodeid) over(partition by id order by statename) as 
first_episodeid,
First_value(episodedate) over(partition by id order by statename) as 
first_episodedate
from 
test_first_value;
```

[image]

Now If I change my insert order then it will always return the row value which was inserted first that is episodeid = 98123 for id = 12 and episodeid = 443467 for id = 13

```
delete from test_first_value;

insert into test_first_value values(12,'MP',98123,'2009-11-06');
insert into test_first_value values(12,'MP',90123,'2017-03-06');
insert into test_first_value values(12,'MP',44567,'2013-03-17');
insert into test_first_value values(12,'MP',9863,'2015-11-06');
insert into test_first_value values(13,'MP',443467,'2016-03-19');
insert into test_first_value values(13,'MP',189300,'2013-03-17');

Select *,
First_value(episodeid) over(partition by id order by statename) as 
first_episodeid,
First_value(episodedate) over(partition by id order by statename) as 
first_episodedate
from 
test_first_value;
```

[image]

Please help me, where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Edit your question and show the "strange result".  You should also explain what results you *want* to get.

Comment: i think you may need `partition by id,statename order by episodedate`

Comment: @Pra you use only statename in order by. So you can't predict what you will have in this case.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Added results.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine.  This is your window function:

```
First_value(episodeid) over(partition by id order by statename)
```

As you yourself show in the data, you have multiple rows for an `id` with the same `statename`.  In this situation, the database will return an arbitrary and indeterminate value from the matching keys.

Another way to say this is that sorting is not stable in relational databases.  The reason is simple:  Tables represent *unordered* sets.  If the sort keys are all the same, then there is no natural ordering to use instead.

So, find another key so the `order by` uniquely identifies each row.  That means that the results will be stable, because the desired row will be uniquely identified.  In your data, you can add `episode_date` as a second key to the `order by`.